# HERE iOS sdk - Maneuvers localization

Tags: ios, localization, here-api

I'm using the [HERE iOS SDK](https://developer.here.com/) and I'm implementing a turn-by-turn navigation.

I'd like to use a default language for languages with **non-latin characters**.

Is it possible to force the `currentManeuver.roadName` localization to a specified language?

The documentation says that `roadName` and the other properties are localized to the locale of the region but doesn't specify if we can change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display language used in the navigation map (NMAMapView):

```
Objective C: useDisplayLanguageFromLocale:(nonnull NSLocale *)locale;

Swift: func useDisplayLanguage(fromLocale locale: Locale) -> Bool


Swift: NMANavigationManager.sharedInstance().map = <Your NMAMapView>
```

[Here iOS SDK NMAMapView](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(im)useDisplayLanguageFromLocale:)

[HERE iOS SDK NMANavigationManager](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMANavigationManager.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMANavigationManager(py)map)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I have tried a device with Greek language (iOS 12.1.4). The map takes the display language precisely but the the `roadName` that I take from the `currentManeuver` has still the greek letters.

Comment: The language of the Navigation Manager depends on the current language of your phone (locale). If you change this to english (or a non greek language), the "roadName" from the the "currentManeuver" will change accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I can't force it to display roads with a specific language. 
I think it may be a nice improvement, because there are some cases where certain locales are not supported, so in those cases you would see an app, for example, with the map in English, the auto-suggestion in English (it's possible to set the result locale for NMAAutoSuggestionRequest) but with the maneuvers in an another language, making the user interface a little bit confusing. Thanks for the support.